# d3 select element with class name that contains a string

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg

Here are a series of paths. each path has that ends either with **_before** or _**after**.

```
<svg>
   <g>
      <path class= "my-class-before" ...></path>
   </g>
   <g>
      <path class= "my-class-before" ...></path>
   </g>
   <g>
      <path class= "my-class-after" ...></path>
   </g>
   <g>
      <path class= "my-class-after" ...></path>
   </g>
</svg>
```

How do I select paths that ends with _before?

```
const beforeSelected = ""; ///How to select element with class that ends  with **_before**.
const bedoreAreas = d3
        .selectAll(beforeSelected)
        .transition()
        .style('opacity', 1);
```

Thanks for helping

Comment: why not give your SVG elements two classes each?

Comment: Are you suggestion something like `class="my-class before"`?  I didn't think about it. Stiil, I wonder whether there's a way to select elements with class name containing a substring. It could as well be an id, a name, so forth.

Comment: It would be more efficient to have multiple classes.

Comment: I ended up rewriting my code to have 2 classes. It was still to know the other way as well

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [documentation](https://github.com/d3/d3-selection):

> Selection methods accept [W3C selector](https://www.w3.org/TR/selectors-api/) strings

Which you can use in your case [attribute selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors), use `$` to specify what the attribute should end with, like this:

```js
const befor = d3
        .selectAll("[class$='-before']")
console.log(befor.size());

const after = d3
        .selectAll("[class$='-after']")
console.log(after.size());
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.15.0/d3.min.js"></script>
<svg>
   <g>
      <path class= "my-class-before"></path>
   </g>
   <g>
      <path class= "my-class-before"></path>
   </g>
   <g>
      <path class= "my-class-after"></path>
   </g>
   <g>
      <path class= "my-class-after"></path>
   </g>
</svg>
```